# Return to method that's not main

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I was hoping someone could help me with a quick problem.

Our teacher either mistyped something, or he wants us to return an array from a method, but he wants it to go from one method to another method, which is not the main method. I've been looking everywhere I possibly can and I can't seem to find anything.
My understanding is that you can only return to the method from which you pass the parameters to a method.

Comment: Can you give the *exact* specification from your professor?

Comment: "My understanding is that you can only return to the method from which you pass the parameters to a method." Yes, that is correct.

Comment: _"My understanding is that you can only return to the method from which you pass the parameters to a method."_ Yes, that's how `return` works: it passes a value to the caller. What's your question?

Comment: Probably meant you should pass it as an argument? `ProcessArray(GetArray())`? And what Code-Guru said

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor what he meant?  I'm afraid it's unlikely that anyone in the Stack Overflow community knows what your professor said (unless he comes here too, of course).

Answer (score 1):

After you get the array back from method1 pass it to method2 
ie

```
static void main(String[] args){
       int[] myArray = new int[10];
       method1(myArray);
       method2(myArray);
```

}

I would also recommend looking up and understanding what pass by reference means

Comment: you could even return an array from a method... int[] method(void)

Comment: But Java is pass by **value**.  Yes, one should learn the difference between pass by reference and pass by value, but I don't see how your suggestion entirely applies...

Answer (score 1):

Methods (other than main) can call other methods (and therefore a method can return to something other than main).  Additionally, you can nest method calls.

For example 1:

```
int bar() {
    return 3;
}

int foo() {
    return 2 * bar();
}
```

And then main calls `foo()` (which in turn calls `bar()`, `bar()` returns to `foo()`, then `foo()` returns to `main`.

Then example 2...

```
int foo(int i) {
    return 2 * i;
}

int bar() {
    return 3;
}
```

Then in main:

```
foo(bar());
```

And in this case, `bar()` is actually still returning to `foo`.